# Flutter, fill the entire screen

Tags: flutter

I am designing an application and I have realized that in different mobiles the screen occupies different dimensions, I would like the size to be proportional to the size of the mobile, so that it always occupies the entire screen without the need to scroll.

[image]

I'd like that the `Screen A` could be look like the `Screen B` no matter of the size of the device.

But I have no idea how to do that, this is my code. I also noticed that because of cards I can't scrolling even having a `ListView` this is not a problem once they get the same size, because then there wont be reason to scroll through

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Gestion de flota'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.exit_to_app,
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              _signOut().whenComplete(() =>
                  navigatorKey.currentState.pushReplacementNamed('/login'));
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  GridView.count(
                    childAspectRatio: (10 / 4),
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: [
                      _getHourStart(),
                      _getHourEnd(),
                      _getDateStart(),
                      _getDateEnd(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  GridView.count(
                    childAspectRatio: (3 / 0.7),
                    crossAxisCount: 1,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: [
                      _getHourStart(),

                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                childAspectRatio: (3 / 2),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: [
                  Card(
                    child: _uploadPic(Foto.primera, picList[0]),
                  ),
                  Card(
                    child: _uploadPic(Foto.segunda, picList[1]),
                  ),
                  Card(
                    child: _uploadPic(Foto.tercera, picList[2]),
                  ),
                  Card(
                    child: _uploadPic(Foto.cuarta, picList[3]),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () async { // more code... }
                child: SubmitButton(context, 'Enviar datos'),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: height * .14),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: instead of using fixed sizes in padding and SizedBox(), you should use dynamic sizes by using MediaQuery.of(context).size

Answer (score 0):

you can use **MediaQuery**

you retrieve the size of mobile screen by:

> final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height

> final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this problem is to add `Expanded` to all the children in the `Column` widget.

Another and preferable one is :

make your `Container` height the height of your screen.

```
  body: Container(
height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
```

next add the mainAxisAlignment property to both `Column` widgets.

```
 child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
]
```